# flexbox containers and children structure

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The problem is whatever I change in one of the children??? classes seems to have no effect on the images?? which is why I've resorted to using style for each image...

```css
/*************************/
/* FLEX container */
/************************/
.fcon {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    min-width: 0;
    background-color: black;

    /* images */
    .lt {
        flex: 30%;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        background-color: black;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
    }

    .m {
        flex: 40%;
        justify-content: center;
        border-style: solid black;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
    }

    .rt {
        flex: 30%;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        border-style: solid black;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
    }

}
```

```html
<!-- The flexible grid (content) -->
<div class="fcon">
    <div class="lt">
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="watchmaker.png"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="hamburger.png"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="wm_my_watches.png"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="wavygravy.png"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="wm_send.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="m">
        <div> <img style="width:200px;" src="left-arrow.gif"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:200px;" src="left-arrow.gif"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:200px;" src="left-arrow.gif"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:200px;" src="left-arrow.gif"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:200px;" src="left-arrow.gif"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rt">
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="Tap.gif"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="Tap.gif"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="Tap.gif"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="Tap.gif"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="Tap.gif"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

For example if I change .rt's justify-content: flex-end ...nothing changes. The icons stay exactly where they are. Similarly if I put width or height attributes into .lt, .rt or .m nothing changes.

So confused right now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is pretty clear, every CSS rule that is applied doesn't give an effect on the layout. Although the big intro, for a new user this is pretty good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your styling the container, for example: when you style '.lt' it will style that entire block (imagine a block around all the children).  If you want to set a size for the children images within your style sheet, you could type something like

```
.lt>div>img {
    width: 200px;
}
```

See the ">" symbol will basically move you down to the next child, so think of it as a tree like structure. container>child>grandchild>so on and so on.

Comment: Sorry about the "big intro" though I'd been pretty clear.

Comment: skaz => Thanks ....so I tried that...!! as I'd seen in the tutorials and somehow it wouldn't work??? Does it override the div's img attributes or will they override the flexbox child class??  I get the tree structure I just don't know why mine isn't working the way I've seen it and you've written it! There must be something else I'm not doing...

Comment: HA! FIXED!!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU. I was doing .lt>img   NOT .lt > div > img.....!!! Such a doughnut. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, we've all been there.  I learned the hardway too =).  'Specificity' within CSS helps target specific items for styling.  So if you set certain styles on a container, but want to change something specific within that container, you just need to target it specifically.  So in your case, it was .lt>div>img.  You could even go deeper down the rabit hole by giving say, one image inside a container a unique ID and then targeting that within the CSS style sheet and changing only its attributes.  And if you used an ID, you'd just target it by #"youruniqueID" { your styles }.

Comment: I wanted to add, Arno below brings up a good point too, don't forget to add that "}" to your .fcon styles so it closes it out.  See Arno's info below.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. That makes things a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Your current CSS haves nesting in it, that isn't valid and will be ignored within the browsers. Nesting CSS can be done with Less or SASS/SCSS but that requires a different setup.

example of nesting CSS that doesn't work:

```
.class {
  display: flex;
  .class2 { color: red; }
}
```

.class2 will not be rendered or used in any way or browser.

You will see without the nesting, your CSS is doing something :-)

```css
/*************************/
/* FLEX container */
/************************/
.fcon {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    min-width: 0;
    background-color: black;

   

}

 /* images */
    .lt {
        flex: 30%;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        background-color: black;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
    }

    .m {
        flex: 40%;
        justify-content: center;
        border-style: solid black;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
    }

    .rt {
        flex: 30%;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        border-style: solid black;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
    }
```

```html
<!-- The flexible grid (content) -->
<div class="fcon">
    <div class="lt">
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="m">
        <div> <img style="width:200px;" src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:200px;" src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:200px;" src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:200px;" src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:200px;" src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rt">
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
        <div> <img style="width:60px; height:60px;" src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Arno => Ok as per your advice I removed the nesting then added width: 200px to the "m" child class and removed it from the style in the div (just tested the first one) and it was ignored. The image just went back to its original size which is about 600px...???